# How to continually monitor in-wall moisture content?

Tags: drywall, moisture

There is an [existing question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1968/how-can-i-measure-water-moisture-content-within-a-wall-cavity) about checking the moisture content of a wall, but I'm looking for continuous in-wall monitoring to check the integrity of the monolithic cladding throughout the house.  Insteon has a water leak detector with a 10 year battery but I'm not certain this can be placed inside a wall for this purpose ( accessed by a dummy wall switch ) as it picks up water vs moisture content.  I would be satisfied if I could embed a sensor into the baseplate inside the exterior walls.

Comment: Is your question is this code legal? If accessible it would be if listed for monitoring.

Comment: I'm in NZ.  Nothing illegal as far as I know.

Comment: What level of moisture do you wish to detect? The water leak detection system you refer to will detect pooling water. This is a definite indication of a moisture problem, but might allow the situation to worsen beyond what you are willing to accept. To detect those conditions conducive to mold growth or rot such as increased humidity, water activity, or moisture content in building materials, a more sophisticated measurement system would be required.

Answer (score 1):

You could contact the following EIMA, US Dept. of Energy, or Oak Ridge National combined these agencies conducted a test starting in 2005 on a building in Hollywood South Carolina and one in Washington State that lasted at least 4 years
to include test in eight climate zones.
I did the installation of the test panels on the South Carolina building.
Test panels included most exterior cladding systems.
Pick up sensors for moisture were placed on the back side of all materials used in the construction of each system
Example Exterior stucco sensor behind finish coat, sensor behind brown coat, sensor behind scratch coat, sensor behind lath, sensor behind vapor barrier and sensor behind sheathing.
Also sensor was placed in wall insulation and the back side of the drywall.
I have missed place my final report from EIMA you should be able to get info from one of the above agencies.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your comfort with DIY electronics, you could rig up an Arduino with 1-wire humidity sensors. 1 Arduino could monitor several sensors, if you can get the wiring to them. The Arduino could either output info to an LCD screen, or anywhere if you hooked up a wifi/ethernet shield.

Definitely not an out-of-the-box solution, but it would do what you need.