# Check wall for moisture: is there something like a fuse but moisture?

Tags: walls, leak, mold, moisture

Is there such a thing like a fuse but for moisture? Some material or dye that can be used to know if a wall or floor is starting to accumulate moisture long before mold appears?

We had a moldy, moist wall, which we had to strip of insulation and dry. There were some issues on the roof (broken roof tile, old chimney) that could have been the cause. The wall is on the first floor, and the mold was growing near the ceiling.

The issues have been fixed. It is not clear where the moisture came from other then 'above' so there is no definitive proof that we have fixed our problems.

But we would like to insulate and plaster the wall again, and start using the room again.
It would be nice to know sooner rather then later next time there is some problem on the roof.

This is a related question: [monitor-in-wall-moisture](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/99655/how-to-continually-monitor-in-wall-moisture-content?noredirect=1&lq=1), but it seems to attract answers involving active, automatic monitoring.

Comment: Perhaps this, but perhaps not. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humidity_indicator_card

Comment: Wall is...concrete?

Comment: @Huesmann it's some kind of large porous dark grey bricks covered with some kind of plaster. It was build in the fifties.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Something like that yes, but suitable to measure humidity inside a living space, so non toxic and reacting to humidity over 50% or 60%.

Comment: @Ivana sounds like concrete block.  Is this a basement wall, or is there no soil on the outside?

Comment: @Huesmann it is the wall on the 1st floor, between two houses. There are no water-pipes in, near or above it. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

There are certainly air humidity sensors, which might serve as a proxy for wall moisture.

There are water sensors which detect leaks onto a surface such as  floor, though I don't think any of them are sensitive enough to measure moisture content of concrete until the surface is actually wet.

Both of those are available in home-automation versions for remote monitoring and triggering actions.

There are also moisture sensors used for construction and woodworking which do probe into a surface. But they're relatively expensive, and I don't know of one intended to be read remotely. And they're local; if just one area is starting to leak, a probe elsewhere won't tell you that.